# RadioButtonList SelectedIndex not changing

Tags: asp.net, postback, radiobuttonlist

i have simple radio button list, with static ListItems which i never change. When user selects radio and press submit button, selected index is back to -1. I am not using any UpdatePanels, i havent changed anything with ViewState (i tried both: enabled and disabled), i have tried AutoEventWireup true and false, all values are unique. Nothing helps.

Page code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="registration">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text="Registration" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="UserCreateButton">
            <table class="registration_table">
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="NameLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelName %>' />
                </td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NameTextBox" autocomplete="off" />
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="SurnameLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelSurame %>' />
                </td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SurnameTextBox" autocomplete="off" />
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="UsernameLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelUsername %>' />
                </td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsernameTextBox" autocomplete="off" />
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="PasswordLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelPassword %>' />
                </td><td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordTextBox" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="SexLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelSex %>' />
                </td><td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="SexList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Not chosen" Value="0" Selected="True" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UserCreateButton" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelRegister %>' OnClick="OnUserCreate" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Page codebehind:

```
public new UserCreatePresenter Presenter
{
    get { return base.Presenter as UserCreatePresenter; }
    set { base.Presenter = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public void OnUserCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Presenter != null)
    {
        Presenter.OnUserCreate(
            NameTextBox.Text,
            SurnameTextBox.Text,
            UsernameTextBox.Text,
            PasswordTextBox.Text,
            SexList.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you binding RadioButtonList or Page in PageLoad?

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code please?

Comment: I am not doing anything in PageLoad or PreInit

Comment: please edit your question and post some code what you doing inside the page

Comment: I added more code. To presenter SelectedValue allways comes equal to 0.

Comment: I did my research and i think that there is a problem with ViewState. If i leave the default selected radio, i get good result, but if i change it, i get 0. I Tried with ViewState enabled and disabled, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the `OnClick="OnUserCreate"`

set handler in Page_init like
`UserCreateButton.click += new System.EventHandler(OnUserCreate);`